# Timestamp comparisons in Google Apps Script don't work with either = or ==

Tags: timestamp

I'm trying to find a matching Timestamp by searching down a column.
I use a message box to follow the progress/check matches.
Using = always returns the alert even when they don't match
Using == never returns a match, even when I know they do.
Can anybody explain my mistake/misunderstanding.
I've tried loads of different forums without finding a solution.

```
function TimeTest(){ // works with single = not ==
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Math');
  ss.activate();
  var day1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(11, 1).getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(day1);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Responses');
  ss.activate();
  var day2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(day2);
  if (day2 = day1) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Timestamps Match");
  }
   if (day2 != day1) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Timestamps Do Not Match");
  } 
}
```

An example timecode is 18/02/2022 11:29:03
I'm manually altering the row in var Day2.... to rows where I know it does or doesn't match

Comment: Please add code, example input and what's your expected output.

Comment: Solved now, using .valueOf()